# Javascript HTML GUI structure

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to recall what the [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/526/dragndrop.png/) GUI component is called? 
Its used to move items from one list to another.

Comment: I don't think there's a well-known name for that component. It's just two lists and a bunch of buttons.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't a single component in and of itself. It's multiple HTML components (w/ some JavaScript) wired together to act as a single component.

Not sure it has a specific name...I usual refer to it as a Dual List.

For the record though, the implementation you have pictured is a bit dated. I would get rid of the buttons in the middle and simply make everything multi-select/drag and drop.

Comment: Thanks Justin.. I remembered it as the same "Dual List". :)

Comment: Heres an example: http://javascriptsource.com/miscellaneous/move-dual-list.html

Comment: Don't get rid of the buttons. Some users don't (or can't) use a mouse and need the buttons. Double-click to move is always a useful feature though, and it doesn't hurt to have drag and drop as well...

Comment: For those interested, jQuery UI has something very similar they call "Sortable," which can allow drag and dropping elements between two lists. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

It's something you have to build up from more basic pieces. It's not a stock component in HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Pointy, I know its not a stock component but I just couldn't recall the name. There are tons of readymade scripts for this task. http://javascriptsource.com/miscellaneous/move-dual-list.html

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard it refered to as `Multi-Select Transfer`, but it is almost always custom design and not a stand-alone HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such element but here is an example jquery ui widget you can use :

http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/